# rigid body transformation with only two points

Tags: python, matrix, 3d, gps, robotics

I have a tractor with two GPS antennas which are mounted at the front of the tractor on either side.

[image: view of the front of the tractor]

I get the position (latitude and longitude) of the right antenna (left in the photo) and the north, east, down projection to the second antenna. I have been attempting to plant straight rows simply using the midpoint of the line between the two antennas. I'm getting a lot more roll than I expected and my rows are far from straight.

I want to know the position of a point on the ground. The point of interest is the center point between the two antennas, projected perpendicular to the line between the antennas. I imagine it as the point at the base of a "T" where the ends of the top bar of the "T" are each antenna and the "T" is allowed to rotate freely such that it points toward the ground. Incidentally, the antennas are 1 m apart and 2.4 m high when operating.  A little bit of roll makes a significant difference.

Here's generally what I think I want:

1. Choose an origin point.  (It's common with farm equipment to use the
   midpoint of the rear axle.)
2. Measure to determine the coordinates of the antennas.
3. Choose the coordinates of the point of interest.
4. Calculate the UTM coordinates for antenna A from the receiver output.
5. Calculate the UTM coordinates of antenna B from the receiver projection.
6. Plug all of this information into a magical equation.
7. Get the UTM coordinates of the point of interest.

6 is the tricky one. I get roll information from the two antennas but I assume that there is zero pitch for now. This simplifies the problem enough that I was able to solve it using simple trig. This morning I'm thinking about how to do it using unit vectors.

I would much prefer to have a general way to do this. Then I would be able to add pitch information (from an IMU/INS) and also determine the position of my hitch, each row of the planter, etc.

From reading other questions here, I think I want to do a rigid body transformation with a constraint (no pitch). Am I close? I strongly prefer a Python solution.

Comment: This might help: http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=671